# I have doubt in forming sentence on summarizing the work progress status

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I have to summaries verbally about  my visit to vendor's work place for seeing the current status of the work in progress to my boss. I have doubts in forming the forming below sentence

1. "I visited vendor's work place last week" Or "I had visited vendor's work place last week" -- Which is correct??
2. "I saw the panel box and metal works were all half way through"  -- is it correct sentence?
3. "they are yet to get the motors and controllers"  -- Doubtful sentence, is this conveys, that the vendor is waiting for the motors and controllers to arrive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The first, with an small addition: "I visited **the** vendor's work place last week."
2. "I saw **that** the panel box and metal works were all half complete". I am assuming that panel box and metal works are technical terms that your boss will understand. I don't.
3. "They are still waiting for the motors and controllers."

Comment: Thank you. Yes. he can understand the technical points on the second point. Could you please explain "I saw the panel box" and  " I saw that the panel box" conveys entirely different meaning? or "I saw the panel box" is not a correct sentence at all? Can I ask for my English language quality/Level here?

Comment: The "that" is by no means essential but I put it in to avoid the risk that your boss would start reading and think the sentence was going to be about you seeing the panel box  rather than seeing how much work ad been done. The whole sentence means the same with or without the that, but imagine if the words "I saw the panel box" were at the bottom of a page. While your boss was turning the page he or she would be thinking "this sentence is about what the panel box looks like".